# How to remove space in front of custom view?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, padding

I am creating a customized home icon. The codes for the customization is as follows,

```
View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_display_options_custom, null);
customView.findViewById(R.id.action_home).setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggle();
        }
    });

actionBar.setCustomView(customView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

This is `action_bar_display_options_custom.xml`,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_home" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> </LinearLayout>
```

This's the screenshot,

> [image]

This is home's icon (that space isn't a part of the image view),

> [image]

So, how can I remove the space in front of the view?

Comment: That space look like it is part of the image view. Set the background color to something like red to see if this is the case. If that is true your image is being scaled somehow. Otherwise maybe just set a negative margin

Comment: @Leo Nguyen You might have set padding or given margin in the parent layout . You can see the same amount of space is there before the second image also, therefore I suppose that the parent layout has been either given padding or margin

Comment: I have the same problem, when I tried to set custom action bar I am stuck with same issue
`ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
  bar.setDisplayOptions(0,ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
  bar.setCustomView(view);
  bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`

Comment: oh.my image is being scaled. thank Cplain and sorry for my stupid

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by adding following lines to my code

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
  getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view); // set custom view here
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding or margin that you have set in the parent layout, that will solve the problem. Please feel free to ask doubts, also do let me know if that solves your problem.